# Hacer un registro de usuarios personalizado en laravel

Tags: laravel, login

estoy creando un login con laravel y debo usar una tabla ya existente para crear los usuarios, he intentado sustituyendo los argumentos que estan el controlador de RegisterController que genera laravel con artisan, pero no me funciona a la hora de enviar los datos, se que la vista conecta con el controlador porque para mostrarla envio datos que quiero enseñar en el formulario y los muestra, el problema es cuando se presiona el boton de registro que no me envia los datos y queda en el mismo formulario.

Aqui esta el controlador como lo tengo y el modelo de la tabla

**EL CONTROLADOR:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Usuario;
use App\TipoUsuario;
use App\Cargo;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $tipousuario=TipoUsuario::all();
        $cargo=Cargo::all();
        return view('auth.register',compact('tipousuario','cargo'));
    }



    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = Usuario::create($request->all())));

        // Usuario::guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/Sistema/index';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

        protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }


    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'CodUsu' => ['required', 'string'],
            'CedUsu' => ['required', 'string'],
            'NombUsu' => ['required', 'string'],
            'ApeUsu' => ['required', 'string'],
            'Cod_Cargo' => ['required', 'string'],
            'ClaveUsu' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'Cod_TipUsu' => ['required', 'string'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Usuario
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Usuario::create([
            'CodUsu' => $data['CodUsu'],
            'CedUsu' => $data['CedUsu'],
            'NombUsu' => $data['NombUsu'],
            'ApeUsu' => $data['ApeUsu'],
            'Cod_Cargo' => $data['Cod_Cargo'],
            'ClaveUsu' => Hash::make($data['ClaveUsu']),
            'Cod_TipUsu' => $data['Cod_TipUsu'],
        ]);
    }

}
```

EL MODELO:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table='Usuarios';

    protected $fillable = [
        'CodUsu', 'CedUsu', 'NombUsu','ApeUsu','CodCargo','ClaveUsu','CodTipUsu',
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['ClaveUsu',];
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->ClaveUsu;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

En el archvo de rutas web.php colocas lo siguiente y deberia funcionar.

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);

Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

[enlace de consulta](https://laraveldaily.com/9-things-you-can-customize-in-laravel-registration/)